# Trying to figure out why an error is returned when trying to add an item to the basket on this website

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We have recently carried out a WooCommerce update and now items cannot be added to the cart. Can you see what it is? I can't. https://www.ourwildlife.studio/product/wildlife-photo-print-rhinoceros-oh-no-by-alex-jones/#tab-additional_information

Thank you

Comment: Check your console.  Looks like there's javascript errors.  You may want to turn off AutOptimize so you can see what the stack trace for that is more clearly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go. JavaScript isn't my specialty, unfortunately.